# Download a webpage completely which has ajax calls after load using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a webpage where many section of the page gets loaded using jQueryAjax after intial load. Now I need to download the web page completey using C#. It should be downloaded once all the ajax call completes.

I tried many ways to do that but didnot get through. Can sombody suggest the best way to handle that?

I have my MVC view like this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page";
}
<div id="Banner" class="divMain" style="height: 92px;" style="margin-left: 0.3em">

</div>

<div style="float:left; width:99.6%">
    <div id="StockPriceCharts" class="div_Chart" style="margin-top:0.1em;margin-left:-0.1em">    

    </div>
    <div id="Rating" class="divMain_48" style="margin-left: 0.3em; min-height:140px">
        <div class="ControlHeader">
            Entity Details</div>
                <div id="dvEntity" >

                 </div>
    </div>
    <div id="FilMeetings" class="divMain_48" style="float:left;">
        <div class="ControlHeader">
            MEETINGS
        </div>
         <div id="dvMeeting" style="height: 119px;" class="loading">

           </div>

    </div>

</div>


<span>
    <input id="IdHidden" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.SymbolId"/>
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    // For Entity Detail
    $.ajax({
        url: '/HomePage/Entity Detail/' + $('#IdHidden').val(),
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { symbolId: document.getElementById("IdHidden").value }
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        $('#dvEntity').html(result);

    })
   .error(function (xhr, status) {
       $('#dvEntity').html('<div style="height:40px;"  class="loading">Failed to load Entities</div>');
   });

   $.ajax({
       url: '/HomePage/GetMEETINGSs/' + $('#IdHidden').val(),
       contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
       type: 'GET',
       dataType: 'html',
       data: { symbolId: document.getElementById("IdHidden").value }
   })
    .success(function (result) {
        $('#dvMeeting').html(result);
    })
   .error(function (xhr, status) {
       $('#dvMeeting').html('<div style="height:40px;"  class="loading">Failed to load Business description</div>');
   });

</script>
```

I have removed some part and put dummy value for brevity. But I have similar more section that are getting loaded via AJAX and there are some static content as well. When I download it ajax section is not getting loaded.

Comment: what did you try? what was the results

Comment: I tried downloading the string in using HTTPWebRequest and then making further requests for associated JS, CSS, image files. But I realized it wont work.

Comment: show us your code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, after page loaded you're loading data with ajax and rendering it with JavaScript.

If so, you have to implement data rendering in `Razor` way (If you're using ASP.NET MVC). Each section should have own partial view. Create a new View and put Partials in it.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var api = new YouWebApiController();
    var sectionData_1 = api.GetSectionData_1();
    var sectionData_2 = api.GetSectionData_2();
    var sectionData_3 = api.GetSectionData_3();

    ViewBag.SectionData_1 = sectionData_1;
    ViewBag.SectionData_2 = sectionData_2;
    ViewBag.SectionData_3 = sectionData_3;

    return new View();
}
```

In your view:

```
<body>
@Html.RenderPartial("SectionPartial_1", ViewBag.SectionData_1);
@Html.RenderPartial("SectionPartial_2", ViewBag.SectionData_2);
@Html.RenderPartial("SectionPartial_3", ViewBag.SectionData_3);
</body>
```

Comment: As per OP's question - he wants to **download** some webpage, not render his own.

Comment: @Jesse Yes that could be one way to achieve it but I dont want to change in the application because it is a old MVC application and very stable. Also we show a progress bar in each section for better user experiance and if I use the above approach I may need to create different view and controller altogether. So looking for some other approaches.

Comment: @Brij how do you expect to download something without building it on the server?

Comment: @RowlandShaw You are correct. To build the complete page, there are multiple round trips involved that I realized later when saw the old application. And that's why it didn't work. But as this is a common requirement to get the html of a page and different flavor of AJAX is used in most of the applications so I assume there must be some soltuion/approach for that. I can use some browser/third party control to do that but I dont want to go in that direction until I know there is no way to do that.

Comment: @Brij AJAX is generally (only) used to react to user interaction without requiring a full post back to the server. It is still good practice (even if only for SEO) to allow fallback for non-JavaScript enabled browsers and allow any page to still have a fully server rendered version, which for your use-case could also be used as the download version.

If your site relies on the AJAX for part of the rendering, then it sounds as if the architecture isn't quite right, so it may actually be worth following Jesse's advice here

Comment: @RowlandShaw I agree with you certain extent.In my case, there wont be a scenario where we need to handle a non-JS enabled browser as it is used in intranet with users have limited option to change settings. Regarding arcitecture, there are other ways. But I dont see any harm in this design. There are numerous applications (mainly which has multiple sections in a page), where I have seen rendering part of the page via ajax. As it gives user a better exp and is not required to wait till whole page loads. Jesse advice is last option, as it's tough to get approval to change the existing app.

Comment: You may fetch all data on server, convert it to json string and merge with the view. The scripts in each section should be modified to load data from page.

Comment: @Brij you can also intercept ajax requests, so sections can be left unmodified.